# How to increase the width of a SharePoint Online List column in a List WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

I am trying to increase the width of a column in a SharePoint Online List Web Part. Unfortunately, none of the suggestions offered in StackExchange work for me. I have been adding JavaScript in a Modern Script Editor Web part as shown below but it is not increasing the width of the column.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-DetailsHeader-cell
{
      width: 310px; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: modern or classic? Some stuff simply cannot be changed with script hacks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommend to create or add ungoverned code on modern SharePoint pages, you need to get started with SPFx:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17290130-bring-back-script-editor-web-part-in-modern-shar

You could consider using json formatting as shown below to increase the width of list column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "green",
    "width": "300px"
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting